# powershell - extract value in between using regex

Tags: regex, powershell

I tried to extract content between 2 sections in Outlook MSG:

part A:

XXXXXXXXXXXXXX

part B:

XXXXXXXXXXXXXX

part C:

I'm using the regex `"(?sm)part A:(.*?)part C:"`. I'm doing it like this because some of the msg doesn't have `part B:`. Is there a way to remove/exclude the `part B:` content from the output? Any help is really appreciated, thanks.

Comment: Could you show your expected output?

Comment: the output is the content where i marked the X.thx

Answer (score 0):

Yes, you add a separate capture block with `(Part B: .*?)?` after the one you desire to capture. This block will only have data if your message has a "Part B".

```
PS K:\> $t="Part A: blabla Part B: bla Part C: bla"
PS K:\> $regex="(?ms)Part A: (.*?)(Part B:.*?)?Part C:"
PS K:\> $t -match $regex
True
PS K:\> $matches

Name                           Value
----                           -----
2                              Part B: bla
1                              blabla
0                              Part A: blabla Part B: bla Part C:


PS K:\> $tt="bla Part A: no wai Part C: here"
PS K:\> $tt -match $regex
True
PS K:\> $matches

Name                           Value
----                           -----
1                              no wai
0                              Part A: no wai Part C:
```

Comment: You need to get `$matches[1]` to get your required value. And finally, add examples, probably from the file that gives you problems.

Comment: thank you for the answers. I managed to solve it using regex and replace.it untidy probably but the result is what i'm expected

Answer (score 0):

Similar to Vespers answer. I would use `$matches` for this as well since your are looking to extract two parts. I am going to use [named matches](http://tasteofpowershell.blogspot.ca/2012/01/named-groups-in-regular-expressions.html) and a slightly different regex pattern.

```psh
$pattern = "(?sm)part A:(?<betweenAB>.*?)\s+part B:(?<betweenBC>.*?)part C:"
If($msg -match $pattern){
    "{0}{1}" -f $matches.betweenAB, $matches.betweenBC 
}
```

`$msg` would contain the content of your message or you could put in place `$msg.Body` if you are using Outlook com object. `?<capturename>` is how you use named matches so that way you can reference the matching property in the `$matches` object. I also put in a `\s+` to remove one of the newlines that should be skipped in your example text.

You can also see the [-f format operator](http://blogs.technet.com/b/pstips/archive/2014/10/18/powershell-s-format-operator.aspx) used here.